# Wikidata SPARQL: how to filter by date range?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This query finds winners of the Nobel Prize for Chemistry.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?when (YEAR(?when) as ?date)
WHERE {
  ?item p:P166 ?awardStat .
  ?awardStat ps:P166 wd:Q44585 .
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?when .
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

[See it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fwhen%20%28YEAR%28%3Fwhen%29%20as%20%3Fdate%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP166%20%3FawardStat%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardStat%20ps%3AP166%20wd%3AQ44585%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardStat%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fwhen%20.%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Now would like to find chemistry prize winners in a period of time (date range).

One approach might be to search for each target year (each *point in time* `P585`) and then concatenate the results.

But a better approach might be to filter the result set from above. For example, filter where the earliest `?date` is "2014" and the latest `?date` is "2017"

However, this filter fails:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?when (YEAR(?when) as ?date)
WHERE {
  ?item p:P166 ?awardStat .
  ?awardStat ps:P166 wd:Q44585 .
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?when .
FILTER(?date <= "2017"^^pq:P585 && ?date > "2014"^^pq:P585)
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

My thought was to specify the string "2014" as a `qualifier` for *point in time* but that didn't work.

**How to modify the Wikidata SPARQL query to find/filter results between two points in time?**

Comment: There are several issues. 1) `?date` isn't bound in the query when you just do it in the projection part. Use `BIND` in the query or just use the `YEAR` function directly in the FILTER. 2) the datatype of the literals is weird. why did you use it? I mean, `YEAR` returns an int value and not something with the property name `P585`. Use `SELECT ... ?date WHERE { ... BIND(YEAR(?when) as ?date)
  FILTER(?date <= 2017 && ?date > 2014) ...}`

Comment: Spot on. How to "use `YEAR` function directly in the `FILTER`". That approach sounds more efficient. Ideally, I would like to use range values like `Q1999` (2014) and `Q25290` (2017) but those property targets are not in the items file. Please post answer and I'll accept. Alternatively, I'll post answer with credit to @AKSW and reference other Stack links that did not show a working solution v. your solution.

Comment: Well, I basically meant to use `FILTER(YEAR(?when) <= 2017 && YEAR(?when) > 2014)` instead of using `BIND` first to get the year. In the end, it doesn't matter I guess and there shouldn't be a difference regarding efficiency or it's more or less negligible.

Comment: If you really want to use the Wikidata entities of years, you could make use of the `startTime` and `endTime` data attached to each year.

Comment: would like to but the values of `startTime` and `endTime` are text strings, not wikidata entities. Am I missing something in your suggestion? We're trying to follow the wikidata approach (entities as `?s` and `?o`; minimize literals; minimize blank nodes, etc.) but date/time still seems to be represented as text (e.g. in non-wikidata SPARQL with data type declaration such as `xsd`)

Comment: `FILTER(YEAR...` seems 'cleaner' to me - we'll standardize on that approach for similar date-range queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on (always high quality) advice from [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw) the best way to select items with dates that occur in a range of dates is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?when (YEAR(?when) as ?date)
WHERE {
  ?item p:P166 ?awardStat .
  ?awardStat ps:P166 wd:Q44585 . 
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?when . 
FILTER(YEAR(?when) <= 2017 && YEAR(?when) > 2014)
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

an alternative is to use `BIND` with `FILTER`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?when (YEAR(?when) as ?date)
WHERE {
  ?item p:P166 ?awardStat .
  ?awardStat ps:P166 wd:Q44585 . 
  ?awardStat pq:P585 ?when . 
BIND(YEAR(?when) as ?date) FILTER(?date <= 2017 && ?date > 2014)
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . }
}
```

The solution uses *point in time* P585. An alternative solution could use *start time* (P580) and *end time* (P582), or *start period* (P3415) *end period* (P3416). Those properties are used to qualify `periods-of-time` in many Wikidata items.

Wikidata does define years, such as 2014 (`Q1999`) and 2017 (`Q25290`). But `years` are not used by most Wikidata items to qualify a `period-of-time`. So we have to use `(YEAR(?when)` as the method to set `?date` and then `FILTER` on `?date`